# interacting user space during system call

Tags: linux-kernel, signals, system-calls

I'm trying to write block device driver that implements read/write operations.
The tricky thing is that the information is not in the hardware, but in a user space process. Therefore, during the read/write system call I would like to interact the user space (i.e. sendign signal to the user space).
However, my user space process catching the signal only after the read/write system call returned. adding wait in the system call implementation seems to be ignored somehow.

### I used this code at the read system call:

```
ssize_t sleepy_read(struct file *filp, char *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos)
{
    struct siginfo info;
    struct task_struct *t;
    int ret;

    #define SIG_TEST 44

    memset(&info, 0, sizeof(struct siginfo));
    info.si_signo = SIG_TEST;
    info.si_code = SI_QUEUE; 
    info.si_int = 1234;
    rcu_read_lock();
    t = pid_task(find_pid_ns(current->pid, &init_pid_ns), PIDTYPE_PID); 
    if(t == NULL){
        printk(KERN_ERR "no such pid\n");
        rcu_read_unlock();
    return -ENODEV;
    }
    rcu_read_unlock();
    ret = send_sig_info(SIG_TEST, &info, t);    //send the signal
    if (ret < 0) {
        printk("error sending signal\n");
    return ret;
    }
    wait_event_interruptible(wq, flag != 0);
    msleep(10000);
    return (0);
}
```

### and this code at user space:

```
#define SIG_TEST 44
int      g_devFile = -1;

void receiveData(int n, siginfo_t *info, void *unused)
{
    printf("received value %i\n", info->si_int);
}

int main(void)
{   
    struct sigaction sig;
    sig.sa_sigaction = receiveData;
    sig.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigaction(SIG_TEST, &sig, NULL);

    g_devFile = open(devname, O_RDWR);
    if ( g_devFile < 0 )  {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error opening device[%s] file       err[%s]\n",devname,strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    } else {
        fprintf (stderr, "device opened. ptr=%p\n", (void*)g_devFile);
    }
    i = read(g_devFile, &buff, 11);
}
```

Currently I'm catching my signal (in user space) only after the 10 seconds sleep expieres (the wait seems to be ignored).
Any idea will be appriceated. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't simply block the `read` call until all the data is read?

Comment: When and how is `flag` changed?

Comment: How do you suggest to block the `read`? do you mean from user space? I cannot control user space. just kernel space.

the flag in the code example is change during the `write` function. but this is just an example. I'm just wanted to find a way to block the `read` system call an enable my user space application cpu time, so it can process the signal that I have just sent to it